# I'm trying to float a <p> tag in a forum setup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently making a forum setup where users can view, post and respond to topics. The bit I'm posting here is the "reply to a topic bit". Where the top post is "Topic", and the "reply" bit is at the bottom. Inbetween I have "posted answers" to said Topic.

The problem I'm having is that the "p" tag wont position itself to the right of the user who posted his/her reply, like the replyfield at the bottom does.

I have tried to copy/paste the reply bit on top of each other, and they align nicely, but once I change the `textarea` tag to a `p` tag it wont work.

NOTE: The posts will later on be converted to actual posts using PHP, this is just for testing

Thanks

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class=forumListWrap>
    <div class="col-1-forum">
        <h2>TITLE</h2><!--TITLE-->
        <button type="button" class="forumBtn">Add a Reply</button>

        <div class="topic">
            <h6>Topic</h6>
            <div class="reply-wrap">
                <div class="col-reply">
                    <div class="profilePicForum">
                        <img src="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="profileInfoForum">
                        <h2>Username</h2>
                        <h3>Posts: 0</h3>
                        <h3><a href="profile.html">View Profile</a></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3-reply">  
                    <div class="postedAnswer">
                        <p>LOREM</p> 
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="reply">
            <div class="reply-wrap">
                <div class="col-reply">
                    <div class="profilePicForum">
                        <img src="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="profileInfoForum">
                        <h2>Username</h2>
                        <h3>Posts: 0</h3>
                        <h3><a href="profile.html">View Profile</a></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3-reply">  
                    <div class="postedAnswer">
                        <p>LOREM LOREM</p> 
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    

    <div id="horiLine"></div>

        <div class="col-2-reply">
            <h2>Reply to thread</h2>
            <div class="profilePicForum">
                <img src="#">
            </div>
            <div class="profileInfoForum">
                <h2>Username</h2>
                <h3>Posts: 0</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3-reply">  
            <div class="answerField">
                <textarea></textarea>
            </div>
            <input id="replySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">        
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

[Please see code.](https://jsfiddle.net/uzahrv4d/)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: I pasted your code into here: https://jsfiddle.net/uzahrv4d/ please add it to your question.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to align and where you want to show it. You have <p> alone in div and you seem to be willing to align it to an element in another div. Is this correct? Add IDs in your code and explain better

Comment: I'm having trouble adding the css to this post, trying to do so with ctrl-k.
I want the p tag positioned to the right. Like the textarea does at the bottom of my code. Immagine a standard forum setup. Where you have the user on the left side, and his/her reply to said forum to the right of profile picture/username

I'm sorry for my explanation, I'm quite new at this, and dont know any other way to explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzahrv4d/2/) for a possible Variant.

Explanation of what i did:

- i set a width for the column with the username (col-3-reply) to 20% and also made it float left
- i set the width of the reply-content to 80%
- i added a antifloat div below. This is because floating elements are treated differently, and by adding this, you can have them still inside the box with the grey border of the reply.

Here are the antifloat CSS rules. See the jsFiddle for all details:

```
.antifloat {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

As a general hint: Check out the new CSS 3 flexbox ( display:flex; ) it has very good support in all modern browser and is way easier to understand,write and read.

Comment: Thank you you kind sir! It worked. Happy camper over here